# Azure app service: Cannot find the certificate in X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I have written a program that needs a certificate for signing and some other things.

I have uploaded my pfx file as private certificate in SSL certificates of my app service.

[image]

Then I've tried to see installed certificates on my app service as it has been described [in here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karansingh/2017/03/15/azure-app-services-how-to-determine-if-the-client-certificate-is-loaded/) by using power shell.

[image]

But my current user doesn't have any certificates.

I've also checked my local machine, but it wasn't there either. 
[image]

I cannot also find it using my c# code:

```
 X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, ThumbPrint, false);
        if (certCollection.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Certificate not found");
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oh, I have forgotten to add WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES valued * in the app settings :|

Hope it can help the next person
[image]

Answer (score 3):

We could get the answer from this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/).

> Adding an app setting named **WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES** with its value set to the **thumbprint** of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application.
>
> You can have **multiple comma-separated** thumbprint values **or** can set this value to **"*"** (without quotes) in which case all your certificates will be loaded to your web applications personal certificate store.